# NSView display causes immediate drawRect call, but subviews changes not shown untill the next NSApp loop step

Tags: cocoa, nsview, redraw

I have programmatically created NSButton as subviews of main window NSView, and wish to change button text color while some long processing is running.

```
[myButton setAttributedTitle:colorTitle];
[myView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

works correct, but only after return to NSApplication loop.
Replacing  **setNeedsDisplay:YES** with **display** causes immediate call of drawRect, but buttons are still not redrawn, while callback process is running.
Is it possible to flush subviews redrawing out of NSApp loop ?

Comment: Are you using something like this: [btn setAction: @selector (myBtnAction:)]; to change the button title color? Is the color changed when it is pressed or at some other time?

Comment: Is "some long processing" blocking the main loop?

Comment: Yes, as I understand, NSApp loop is waiting, while NSButton 'setAction' procedure is running (is it correct ?).  I can start new thread on button click, but that needs more efforts for synchronization, so I would prefer to use single thread, if possible.

Comment: ```NSRange titleRange = NSMakeRange(0, [buttonTitle length]);
    [colorTitle addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:titleRange];
    [button setAttributedTitle:colorTitle];```
This is color change code. I noticed also, that color is changed if I call NSAlert, may be it runs its own events processing loop.

Comment: Are you trying to change a button's title color with drawRect()?